# How do I change the title of a PowerPoint exported to PDF?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm uploading a PDF exported from a PowerPoint file to my website. However, it shows "PowerPoint Presentation" as the title:

[image: title]

How do I change this?

Comment: How about posting a link to an example so anyone interested in helping can have a look?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Click on `File` and on the top right and then `Info`. You will be able to see the `Properties` of your document there and also change the title that will be used when saving it as PDF.

[image: set title for PDF export in Office 2016]

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I found the answer for PowerPoint. Open your PowerPoint file, then under the file tab, under Info, on the right side, you'll see Properties. Under Properties, one item is "title" and when you hover of the title an editing box appears. Change it there.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of the older answer.